# Shell script to recursively find and list largest files, ask confirmation to remove them and, if confirmed, remove them

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script that recursively finds the largest files with .log extension and lists them out. It has to further ask for the confirmation to remove them. If confirmed, it has to delete that file. I'm new to shell scripting and the closest I got to was this:

`#!/bin/bash
cd /
find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec du -sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 10`

This lists out top 10 .log files(largest file first). But, I've no clue how to continue from here. How do I parse this list and ask for the confirmation for removing each file and proceed accordingly? 
please help

Comment: Why do you say your script needs to be recursive? (This means that your script needs to call itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rm -i $(find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec du -sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 10)
```

Basically, taking the output of your find command and using it with "rm -i"  The "rm -i" forces the rm command to be interactive.  It will prompt you if you want to remove a file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of the `printf` function within `find`, you can easily list all files and sort them according to their size:

```
find . -iname '*log' -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -z -k1rn
```

We use here the `\0` as a line terminator to avoid any issues with possible "funny" filenames. This output can now be piped to a simple while loop that does the queries:

```
find . -iname '*log' -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -z -k1rn \
    | while read -r -d  $'\0' size file; do
         echo "size: $size"
         echo "file: $file"
         while true; do
            read -p "Do you wish to delete this file (y/n) or quit (q)?" ynq
            case "$ynq" in
                [Yy]* ) rm "$file" ;;
                [Nn]* ) continue   ;;
                [Qq]* ) exit       ;;
                * ) echo "Please answer yes/no or quit.";;
            esac
         done
      done
```